# DataFrame has 50 partitions without calling repartitions() method and after calling repartitions() method to create partitions based on columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark

When trying to create partitions based on two columns Dataframe creates 50 partitions when calling repartition() method. The same number of partitions created without calling repartitions() method.

The same number of partitions created without calling repartitions() method.

```
inJoin = df1.join(df2, Seq(t.get_joinkey()(0), t.get_joinkey()(1))).repartition(col("IMT_ID"), col("BRAND_SUB_SUBGROUP_ID"))
```

when calling repartition method it should create partitions based on columns.

Comment: Sorry, what exactly is your question?

Comment: 50 partitions are created after I call repartition() method or I don't call any method to create partitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not specified number of partitions as an argument of the `repartition` function, so it used the value specified in `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` property.

However, join, if it involves shuffle, also repartitions data in number of partitions specified in this property.

That's why the numbers should be the same.

You may pass a different number of partitions as another parameter if you wish:

`repartition(100, col("IMT_ID"), col("BRAND_SUB_SUBGROUP_ID")`

---

Here are the excerpts from the documentation:

[On repartition method:](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@repartition(partitionExprs:org.apache.spark.sql.Column*):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[T])

> `repartition(partitionExprs: Column*): Dataset[T]`
>
> Returns a new Dataset partitioned by the given partitioning
>   expressions, using spark.sql.shuffle.partitions as number of
>   partitions.

---

> `repartition(numPartitions: Int, partitionExprs: Column*): Dataset[T]`
>
> Returns a new Dataset partitioned by the given partitioning
>   expressions into numPartitions.

---

And documentation for `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` configuration property:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-performance-tuning.html#other-configuration-options

> Configures the number of partitions to use when shuffling data for
>   joins or aggregations.